# .exe bulit by Pyinstaller lost some functions

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, spyder

I created a small application with Pyqt (Anaconda) which monitors few directories, and sends signal when changes occur furthermore does some action. However, when I make an stand-alone exe file using Pyinstaller, the application does not function correctly. I starts, I can choose the directories, but when I copy files into them, the expected action is not happening...when I run from code it works perfectly...Any idea what can be the problem?

I have to following setup:

2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score -1):

I add a similar problem and I solve it by replacing '/' in file path to '\'
If I don't do that, it work when executed in python but not with .exe.

```
fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open Data File" , "", ".py data files (*.py)")
if fileName[0]=='':
    return
fileName = str(fileName[0])
fileName=fileName.replace('/','\\')
(filepath, filename) = os.path.split(fileName)
```

I don't know if that can solve your issue too, since you haven't put your script.

Comment: the problem was that the QFileDialog returned a QStringList, and when I made some action on it I considered that is a normal list and that caused the trouble. Even though it worked when executed in python, did not work with .exe...